# Booting an Operating System

Tags: operating-system

In the textbook Operating Systems Concepts, 9th edition. The authors state the following :

> The procedure of starting a computer by loading the kernel is known as
> booting the system. On most computer systems, a small piece of code
> known as the bootstrap program or bootstrap loader locates the kernel,
> loads it into main memory, and starts its execution. Some computer
> systems, such as PCs, use a two-step process in which a simple
> bootstrap loader fetches a more complex boot program from disk, which
> in turn loads the kernel.

So we have two ways to boot an OS. My question is why do we have 2 different ways? I mean the first way is enough and more efficient as it is a one-step process for booting the OS?

Comment: The two-step process is needed when the bootstrap loader is too big for the one-step process.  The first bootstrap is very small -- generally one disk or device block.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thanks alot. But what makes a bootstrap loader too big or small?

Comment: It depends on how much it does and how complex it is.  The more complex a program is, the larger it will tend to be.  You can see this with the size of any executable.  If the bootloader needs an entire filesystem implementation in it, that's probably too big for the first stage.  Having a decompression library (in order to boot a compressed kernel) may make it even bigger.